# It was decided that the old building (should/would) be pulled down

Tags: sentence-meaning

> (1) It was decided that the old building **be pulled down**.
>
> (2) It was decided that the old building **should be pulled down**.
>
> (3) It was decided that the old building **would be pulled down**.

[(1) and (2) are from one of my English-Japanese dictionaries. (3) is
my sentence.]

**Question:** Do these three sentences have the same meaning?

[According to the dictionary, (1) and (2) have the same meaning.]

Answer (score 4):

They are all correct grammar.

1. Uses a subjunctive clause.  This is restricted to formal English in modern styles (and learners should usually avoid it, except in fixed phrases)
2. Uses "should", this means the same as "ought to".  It would be good if the building gets pulled down. In this case you don't know if the build did get pulled down.
3. Uses "would", which in this context I understand as "future in the past".  The future "will" but in a past context can be expressed with "would".  The time when the building gets pulled down is in the future of the meeting.  But the meeting is in our past.

Comment: Thank you, James. Do (1) and (2) have the same meaning?

Comment: Not exactly.  The subjunctive goes with the verb "decided" and means that only the decision was made to pull down the building. It doesn't indicate the sense of "ought to".

Comment: Thank you. Do (1) and (3) mean virtually the same thing?

Comment: Much the same, but you only need to add a few words and you can get a different interpretation of "would".  It is also used for conditional clauses.  "...would be pulled down if no buyer was found"